# React update dropdown menu siblings with leftover items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create dropdown menus that update their selections based on what was already chosen. I have lifted the state to the best of my ability (state is being passed down two levels, as shown below):

selects.jsx:

```
class Selects extends Component {

    render() {

        const {selectBoxes, handleDropdown} = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                {selectBoxes.map(selectBox => (
                    <SelectBox 
                        key={selectBox.id}
                        strategies={selectBox.strategies} 
                        selectBox={selectBox}
                        handleDropdown={handleDropdown}
                        >
                    </SelectBox>
                    ))}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Selects;
```

selector.jsx:

```
function SelectBox(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [strategy] = React.useState('');
    

    //const handleChange = event => {
    //    setStrategy(event.target.value);
    //};

    const textMap = {
        1:'Top pick',
        2:'Second pick',
        3:'Third pick'
    };

    return (
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Strategy {props.selectBox.id}</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                    value={strategy}
                    onChange={props.handleDropdown}
                >
                    <MenuItem value="">
                        <em>None</em>
                    </MenuItem>
                    {props.strategies.map(strategy => (
                        <MenuItem value={strategy}>{strategy}</MenuItem>
                    ))}

                </Select>
                <FormHelperText>{textMap[props.selectBox.id]}</FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
    );
}

export default SelectBox;
```

Which is populated from values from the `state` of my app.js:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = { 
    selectBoxes: [
        {id:1, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
        {id:2, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
        {id:3, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
    ]

...


handleDropdown = e => {
  const menuItem = e.target.value;
  this.setState({menuItem});

  const leftoverChoices = this.state.selectBoxes.filter(c => c.id !== e.target.value);
  this.setState({leftoverChoices});
};

...

render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Selects 
          selectBoxes={this.state.selectBoxes}
          handleDropdown = {this.handleDropdown}
        />
       </div>
)
}
```

On the page though, the menus don't work. Once you choose an item, the dropdown menu doesn't display it -- nor do the sibling menus remove the item to show only leftover choices.

### Question

Why is the menu item logic not working as expected? Would it not be appropriate to dual-purpose the `handleDropdown` function to also update other dropdown menus with leftover choices?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following code, you need to bind the context of the owner component of `handleDropdown` function because you want to change the state of the owner component. If you execute it without binding the context, then it will try to search and update the state of that component from which it is executed. And also please check the `handleChange` funcion of the `SelectBox` component. You need to set the state of the `SelectBox` value, otherwise it won't render when different `MenuItem` are selected.

---

App.jsx

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = { 
            selectBoxes: [
                {id:1, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
                {id:2, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
                {id:3, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
            ]
        }
    }


    handleDropdown = e => {
        const menuItem = e.target.value;
        this.setState({menuItem});

        const leftoverChoices = this.state.selectBoxes.filter(c => c.id !== e.target.value);
        this.setState({leftoverChoices});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Selects 
                    selectBoxes={this.state.selectBoxes}
                    handleDropdown = {this.handleDropdown.bind(this)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

SelectBox.jsx

```
function SelectBox(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [strategy, setStrategy] = React.useState('0');
    

    const handleChange = event => {
       setStrategy(event.target.value);
       props.handleDropdown();
    };

    const textMap = {
        1:'Top pick',
        2:'Second pick',
        3:'Third pick'
    };

    return (
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Strategy {props.selectBox.id}</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                value={strategy}
                onChange={handleChange}
            >
                <MenuItem value="0">
                    <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                {props.strategies.map(strategy => (
                    <MenuItem value={strategy}>{strategy}</MenuItem>
                ))}

            </Select>
            <FormHelperText>{textMap[props.selectBox.id]}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
    );
}

export default SelectBox;
```

---

Selects.jsx

```
class Selects extends Component {

    render() {

        const {selectBoxes, handleDropdown} = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                {selectBoxes.map(selectBox => (
                    <SelectBox 
                        key={selectBox.id}
                        strategies={selectBox.strategies} 
                        selectBox={selectBox}
                        handleDropdown={handleDropdown}
                        >
                    </SelectBox>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Selects;
```